# React Native. How to render dynamic catalog's menu?

Tags: reactjs, native

Lets imagine, that we have some catalog, let it be the goods catalog. You have top level categories and many subcategories for them and so on deeper. The whole menu can be of any deep.Of course I don't want to hardcode this catalog, I want to load its structure from a remote server (REST API for instance), so that I could change it any time wothout posting changes to apps

I am using React-navigation (if it makes any sense). How it is usually done?(1) Should I somehow create one page and pass there some parameters, or (2) should I create many distinct pages.In the first case (1) I can't even imagine, how can I pass new parameters to the same page again and again in such a way that each time there would be a new title in header of this page and a new submenu structure to be displayed.The second way (2) seems rather complex to me and is not the best idea... I suppose.What are best practices?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONTRu.png)